# Python defaultdict значение по умолчанию

Tags: python

```
some_defaultdict = defaultdict(list)
some_defaultdict = defaultdict(lambda x: 5)
```

Параметр `defaultdict` должен быть callable. Почему именно вызываемый? С чем связано такое архитектурное решение?

Comment: При обращении к несуществующему ключу, переданный в конструктор callable просто вызывается, а возвращённое значение присваивается этому ключу. Просто, удобно, эффективно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего причина в том, что если бы просто задавалось значение по-умолчанию, то пришлось бы учитывать те случаи, что в Python большинство типов изменяемы, и при выборе значения по-умолчанию изменяемого типа (например, `[]`) может получиться что мы будем менять значение по какому-то ключу, а значение поменяется для всех ключей.

Пример (аналог `defaultdict` со значением по-умолчанию вместо функции-инициализатора):

```
class MyDefaultDict:
    def __init__(self, initial=None, default=None):
        self._default = default
        if initial is not None:
            self._d = dict(initial)
        else:
            self._d = dict()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self._d:
            self._d[key] = self._default

        return self._d[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyDefaultDict(%r, default=%r)' % (self._d, self._default)
```

Дальше тестируем класс:

```
>>> d = MyDefaultDict(default=[])

>>> d
MyDefaultDict({}, default=[])

>>> d['a']
[]

>>> d['b']
[]

>>> d
MyDefaultDict({'b': [], 'a': []}, default=[])

>>> d['a'] is d['b']
True  # видим, что под разными ключами лежит один и тот же объект

>>> d['a'].append(1)

>>> d
MyDefaultDict({'b': [1], 'a': [1]}, default=[1])  # Fail(((
```

Можно, конечно, не тупо подставлять значение по-умолчанию, а делать копию - но тогда какую: поверхностную, глубокую? И как копировать пользовательские классы, не залезая глубоко в их структуру?

А проще всего-навсего передавать функцию, создающую объект нужного класса (например `list`) или `lambda` для каких-то конкретных значений или специальных случаев (мне однажды понадобился `defalutdict`, значение по-умолчанию у которого тоже `defaultdict`).

В общем, пусть лучше пользователь `defaultdict` сам заботится, как будут создаваться значения по-умолчанию.